# How can I do an explicit wait in selenium with this code?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to click on some image links and then retrieve the the urls and save them as jpgs. I keep retrieving the url of the page before the image url I want to retrieve.

It saves jpgs files with timestamps but there are no images because i'm getting the wrong urls.

```
ts = time.time()
WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/head/meta")))

img_url = driver.current_url


print img_url

urllib.urlretrieve(img_url, "/home/ro/A_Python_Scripts/tumblrr_auto/Pics/test_pics/%d.jpg" %(ts))
```

When I click on the links I get some html like this.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height;">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resource://gre/res/ImageDocument.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resource://gre/res/TopLevelImageDocument.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="chrome://global/skin/media/TopLevelImageDocument.css">
<title>3760968-1135171246-cc%5B.jpg (JPEG Image, 704 × 400 pixels) - Scaled (91%)</title>
```

I can get it to work with an implicit wait but I need an explicit wait really.

Comment: try `driver.implicitly_wait(1000)` or adjust the seconds(i.e.1000) or use `time.sleep(1000)` if it is wait related problem. If problem is not solved then add details of the scenario (e.g. url,what dom you want) whereas i can help. Why u are using selenium and urllib?

Comment: hi yeah sorry I should of mentioned I can get to to work if I use an implicit wait I kind of had my heart set on having it work with an explicit wait; the script is really slow as it is but thanks anyway.

Comment: of course it will be slow `1000` seconds hehe! you can use `explicit wait` to overcome this- no need to use both selenium and urllib.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are waiting for the `META` tag to exist. It likely already exists on the page you start on so there is no wait and the execution continues which gets you the current page's URL.

What I typically do in cases like this is one of two things:

1. Either wait for a specific (unique) element on the 2nd page... something that exists on the 2nd page but not the first.

or

2. Wait for an element on the 1st page to go stale (indicating the browser is changing pages) and then get the element I want (from the second page)

I don't know enough about your pages to provide specific code but here are some examples

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "some id that exists on page2 but not on page1")))
// once the line above passes, I know I'm on the second page... do stuff
```

or

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.staleness_of((By.ID, "some id that exists on page1 but not on page2")))
// once the line above passes, I know I'm transitioning to the second page... do stuff...
// may need to wait for an element on the 2nd page to exist, be clickable, etc.
```

The examples above are using IDs but those may not be available so you can change them to whatever applies.

Comment: Thanks for this, I couldn't figure it out so I started on another project but I'll try this out and post back here.